# Best way to create different zones in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is my demo lvl, made in blender:

[image]

think of it as two prallel walls,, the player can walk "through" them, exiting and entering the tunnel at any point

what i want is, to have a flag on the player,..  player inside the tunnel? = true.. outside = false. and the flag is updated at all times

so i had few solutions in mind .. i'll list them .. im a beginner, and i think there has to be a better way than what i have in mind . so bear with me

1- ray casting...  have multiple nodes scattered across the tunnel, especially at corners.. if the player can raycast the nearest node, without the ray hitting the wall first.. then he is inside.. .. 
well, this may have many problems.. no need to list them all :D

2- trigger zones.. have huge cube meshes around the tunnel. once the player leaves the zone mesh.. he is flagged outside.. 
great, except that it wont be accurate, as the wall is curvy as hell :D . .

3- draw a plane between the tunnel walls.. as in floor.. if the player is ontop of that specific plane. then he is inside the tunnel
thing is, i dont plan to make a floor.. but if i have to. then be it

4- draw a train of low resolution cubes ,  along and inside the walls.. and make them act as triggors.. so each time the player crosses the wall, he will pass through them, and they will trigger.. i might have to have two parallel trains at each side.. to    figure out, whether the player is actually leaving the tunnel, or entering it

i know its a very basic question, but i think i can do better than the previous solutions i offered :(
thanks

Comment: Are you in 2D or 3D? If 2D you can use the polygon collider as trigger.If 3D, I would place a set of box colliders that are close enough to the shape and same again as triggers.

Comment: im 3D.
so basically solution 4 :)..

Comment: I would use a set of box colliders indeed, you could use mesh collider but I feel it would be a lot of details that you don't really need.

Comment: A mesh collider would work quite well, it doesn't need to be as high-poly as the actual geometry, but it would let you have the same resolution of detail as the cubes but using a single collider.  As long as a mesh collider doesn't perform any translation or rotation, Unity doesn't have to recalculate the collision zones.

Comment: yea im doing that right now, thanks :)

Comment: Not exactly answering, but, if you post this question on Unity Answers you may have other opinions.

Comment: oh, thanks... didnt know

Answer (score 0):

You could use the solution 2, the triggers can overlap and have different shapes (box, sphere). This way you can get a more accurate tunnel information.

Aways try to avoid mesh colliders due performance issues.

Just in case:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html